# Null reference exception thrown on attempt to dynamically populate ASP.NET MenuItem

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I'm trying to populate an `ASP Menu` with `ASP MenuItems` dynamically from the code behind, but am getting an `object reference is not set to an instance of an object` exception.

This is what my ASP looks like:

```
<asp:Menu ID="HeaderMenu" runat="server">
    <Items>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

And this is what my code behind looks like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateMenu();
}

protected void PopulateMenu()
{
    HeaderMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem 
    {
        Text = "Register Now!",
        NavigateUrl = "~/Pages/Register.aspx"
    });
}
```

It's throwing the exception on calling Add, but I can't figure out why.

EDIT: PopulateMenu() is being called on page load

Comment: when u call this function?

Comment: Your code works for me.  How are you calling PopulateMenu?

Comment: Where you are calling this method?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: I bet that `HeaderMenu.Items == null`, assuming that `HeaderMenu != null`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. Provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<asp:Menu ID="HeaderMenu" runat="server">
    <Items>
    </Items>
</asp:Menu>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateMenu();
}

protected void PopulateMenu()
{
    HeaderMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem 
    {
        "Register Now!",
        "","", 
        "~/Pages/Register.aspx"
    });
}
```